# Problems with flask and bad request

Tags: flask, angular5, flask-mysql

I was programming myself a pretty nice api to get some json data from my gameserver to my webspace using json,

but everytime i am sending a request using angular i am getting this:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2018 17:07:33] code 400, message Bad request version
> ("▒\x9c▒▒{▒'\x12\x99▒▒▒\xadH\x00\x00\x14▒+▒/▒,▒0▒\x13▒\x14\x00/\x005\x00")
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2018 17:07:33] "▒\x9dtTc▒\x93▒4▒M▒▒▒▒▒\x9c▒▒{▒'\x99▒▒▒▒H▒+▒/▒,▒0▒▒/5"
> HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2018 17:07:33] code 400, message Bad request syntax
> ('\x16\x03\x01\x00▒\x01\x00\x00\x9d\x03\x03▒k,&▒▒ua\x8c\x82\x17\x05▒QwQ$▒0▒▒\x9f▒B1\x98\x19W▒▒▒▒\x00\x00\x14▒+▒/▒,▒0▒\x13▒\x14\x00/\x005\x00')
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2018 17:07:33] "▒\x9d▒k,&▒▒ua\x8c\x82▒QwQ$▒0▒▒\x9f▒B1\x98W▒▒▒▒▒+▒/▒,▒0▒▒/5"
> HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2018 17:07:33] code 400, message Bad request syntax
> ('\x16\x03\x01\x00▒\x01\x00\x00▒\x03\x03)▒▒\x1e\xa0▒\t\r\x14g%▒▒\x17▒▒\x80\x8d}▒F▒▒\x08U▒ġ▒▒\x06▒\x00\x00\x1c▒+▒/▒,▒0▒')
> g%▒▒▒▒\x80\x8d}▒F▒U▒ġ▒▒▒▒+▒/▒,▒0▒" HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST -

My api

```html
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/punishments": {"origins": "http://localhost:5000" "*"}})
mysql = MySQL()

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'test'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'Biologie1'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'test'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/punishments', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin(origin='localhost:5000',headers=['Content- Type','Authorization'])
def get():
    cur = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cur.execute('''select * from test.punishments''')
    r = [dict((cur.description[i][0], value)
              for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return jsonify({'punishments' : r})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My client function

```html
export class ApiUserService {

  private _postsURL = "https://localhost:5000/punishments";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getPosts(): Observable<Punishments[]> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    return this.http
      .get(this._postsURL,{
        headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
      })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return <Punishments[]>response.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems you are sending a malformed request. You probably don't want to set the 'content-type' header on the *request*. Another possible reason is that you're trying to do a cross-origin request. Do you see any client-side errors?

Answer (score 146):

I had the same error as yours.

My flask server was installed inside `respberry-pi` and I was trying to access it using `https://ip:5000`.

The problem was I was using `https` instead of `http`.

When I changed it to `http://ip:5000`, it worked.

Comment: I am stuck for 4 hrs on this in a similar situation. So simple and so logical.

Comment: The beauty of stackoverflow is that your answer can save someone's time.

Comment: You literally saved me! I forgot to remove "s" from the test from an API to another!!

Comment: What if it's not the solution? I get the same error doing this and the url is getting back to `https` for some reason!

Comment: @AlexJolig Sorry Alex I don't exactly know the problem you are facing but it can be some conf (in your local network, router or the HTTP server) which is redirecting you to `HTTPS`. Check for conf like use/force https always is set to true.

Comment: i created an account to thank you

Comment: Good heavens. Yes, this exactly solved my problem too.... Well,... now I need to look up how to do https:// on Flask... but not today.

Answer (score 18):

I also faced same problem

use only http not https :-

```
http://ip:portnumber
```

Comment: Someone hand this person a medal please.

Comment: I don't see how this differs from Prakash's answer given a year earlier...

Answer (score 8):

Recently I also faced this, the problem came from the SSL config on my app.
In my **.env** I set the `SSL_DISABLE` to `False`, then I change it to `True`.

change `SSL_DISABLE=False` to `SSL_DISABLE=True`

So, the point here is are: check your URL, maybe be it something like: `https://127.0.0.1:5000`, just change it to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

Hope it helps to someone who also facing this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i was trying to debug SocketIo server running on flask. I was trying to access the server using **`wss://`** which was causing the bad request. Changing it to **`ws://`** resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i resolve the problem reverting flask version to Flask==1.1.4 and jinja dependency to Jinja2==3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents - in our case we were using Kubernetes and the ingress annotation was directing health checks to use HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP.

This was the setup -

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTPS`

And the following change fixed it

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP`