# Getting requests.exceptions.SSLError when using post in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using requests to post data to this [Auth0 api](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#signup), here's the code

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=OrgUser)
def user_is_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        full_name = instance.full_name
        first_name = instance.first_name
        last_name = instance.last_name
        email = instance.email
        cell = instance.cell
        password = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=15))
        url = "https://127.0.0.1:8080/dbconnections/signup"
        user_data = {
            'client_id': config("APP_CLIENT_ID"),
            'connection': config("DATABASE_CONNECTION"),
            'full_name': full_name,
            'first_name': first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
            'email': email,
            'password': password,     
            'cell': cell,
        }
        r = requests.post(url, json = user_data, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'}, verify=False)
    else:
        pass
```

I'm getting the following erroe message

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /dbconnections/signup (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:1091)')))
```

I searched for similar questiones but nothings helped so far.

I also have these two lines in the terminal after runnig the code

```
[07/Oct/2022 15:08:12] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00Ý\x01\x00\x00Ù\x03\x03}\x9aP\x98|9\x9eÁ±XÀ\x97C)G@¶\x880G\x80õ\x87u÷,\'"µ\x96ü@\x00\x00bÀ0À,À/À+\x00\x9f\x00\x9eÀ2À.À1À-\x00¥\x00¡\x00¤\x00')
[07/Oct/2022 15:08:12] You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. In my url I instead of

```
"https://127.0.0.1:8080/dbconnections/signup"
```

I had to put

```
"https://my-auth0-domain/dbconnections/signup"
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can come about when an outdated version of pyOpenSSL exists within an environment. It may be worthwhile to to uninstall pyOpenSSL if the version is old and and reinstall reinstall a newer version.

Similar problem:
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4246

Comment: also I saw this line in the terminal
[07/Oct/2022 14:35:13] code 400, message Bad request version ('À(À$À\x14À')

Comment: Consider using http instead of https in your url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389535/problems-with-flask-and-bad-request

Comment: Hmm, I used http but I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: I didn't have pyopenssl at all, I installed version 22.1.0 but the error is still the same.